# No puedo correr ningún código. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript

Hoy, luego de estar una semana fuera de la oficina absolutamente todos mis códigos Javascript presentan el error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.

Son códigos probados y andando, no puedo encontrar solución por ningun lado.
A continuación pongo un código de ejemplo que me tira ese error, pero me lo hace con absolutamente todos.

A alguien se le presentó alguna situación similar??
Ya probé con `$live-server` con `$node` y con distintas consolas.

El error que me tira en consola es el siguiente:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1055:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

```js
class Pakiman
{
    constructor(n, v, a)
    {
        this.imagen = new Image();
        this.nombre = n;
        this.vida = v;
        this.ataque = a;
        this.tipo = "tierra";

        this.imagen.src = imagenes[this.nombre];
    }
    hablar ()
    {
        alert(this.nombre);
    }
    mostrar (){
     
        document.body.appendChild(this.imagen);
        document.write("<br /> <strong>" + this.nombre + "</strong> <br />");
        document.write("Vida: " + this.vida + "<br />");
        document.write("Ataque: " + this.ataque + "<hr />");
    }
}

var imagenes = [];
imagenes["Cauchin"] = "vaca.png";
imagenes["Pokacho"] = "pollo.png";
imagenes["Tocinauro"] = "cerdo.png";

var coleccion = [];
coleccion.push(new Pakiman("Cauchin", 100, 30));
coleccion.push(new Pakiman("Pokacho", 80, 50));
coleccion.push(new Pakiman("Tocinauro", 120, 40));

for(var paki of coleccion){
    paki.mostrar();
}

for(var x in imagenes) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PakimanDex!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pakimanes que he atrapado!</h1>

        <script src="pakiman.js">
        </script>
        <script src="paki.js">
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor, te recomiendo agregar el código para poder saber donde radica tu error

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, edité el post y puse un código que se que está bien escrito pero no anda en mi sesión. Como bien aclaro en el post me sucede con absolutamente todos mis códigos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows

Al parecer los archivos de Node.js estaban corruptos, la solución consiste en hacer una desinstalación limpia siguiendo los pasos de la respuesta provista por brandonscript en stackoverflow inglés:

How to remove Node.js from Windows:

1. Inspire profundamente(no estoy seguro por qué hace referencia a esto).
2. En consola ejecuta  `npm cache clean --force`
3. Desinstala Node.js mediante Aplicaciones y Características.
4. Reinicia.
5. Busca las siguientes carpetas y elimínelas junto con su contenido si es que todavía quedan rastros luego de la desinstalación:

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
   C:\Program Files\Nodejs
   C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (o %appdata%\npm)
   C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (o %appdata%\npm-cache)
   C:\Users{User}.npmrc (chequear sin existe el prefijo . )
   C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-*
6. Chequea tu variable de entorno %PATH% para asegurarte que no existen referencias a Nodejs o npm.
7. Si todavía no está desinstalado por completo, tipea `where` `node` en la consola de Windows y te mostrará donde reside -- elimina la ubicación (y el directorio raíz también).
8. Resetea, para mayor cuidado.

Luego de seguir los pasos se efectúa una instalación limpia de Nodejs.

Comment: Si es posible, incluye una breve descripción de lo que nos compartes como _respuesta que te funcionó_. En unas horas (o días?) podrás marcar tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Buenísimo, creo que lo mejor para futuras referencias es copiar/pegar la respuesta sin quitar la fuente y marcar tu propia respuesta como válida.

Comment: bruno pero que tal si redactas la pregunta y la respuesta que encontrastes, asi tenemos la version en español, el ejemplo que tienes no tiene que ver nada con la respuesta(en primera instancia)